# Bond0 Error: Found a client with no channel in client's hash table

Tags: linux, networking

I have tried to add a new IP on the CentOS system. I copied one of the exiting file in network-scripts directory and modified it, correctly replaced new IP,gateway, netmask, and file name but when i restart network service, i see following:

[image]

Here is new file i added to network-scripts directory.

```
cat ifcfg-bond0.996
DEVICE=bond0.996
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=162.245.12.240
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
USERCTL=no
VLAN=yes
GATEWAY=162.245.12.1
```

Please help me resolve the issue, what im doing wrong?

Here are some more info:

```
[root@CH3CSSD02-0609 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

[root@CH3CSSD02-0609 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
BONDING_OPTS="mode=6 miimon=100"
USERCTL=no
MTU=9000
```

Regards
Aun

Comment: Do you correctely configure the switch ?

Comment: Switch is working fine, as IPs other than this new one, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to create VLAN on top of bonded interface. Bond0 is your bonded interface.
Bond0.996 will be VLAN 996, so you are going to tag packets from this interface.
This requires that your switch port connected to your server eth0 and eth1 be in a trunk mode (but that's not the issue here). 
So please update your question and post following

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
```

And also have a look here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_a_VLAN_over_a_Bond.html

**Edit 1:**
Since you are running CentOS 7 - check this link

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Network_Bonding_Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html

You are missing `BONDING_MASTER=yes` in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0`

Comment: Here are outputs for above two commands:

[root@CH3CSSD02-0609 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)


[root@CH3CSSD02-0609 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
BONDING_OPTS="mode=6 miimon=100"
USERCTL=no
MTU=9000